# Yeoman - modifying default sub generators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Using **Yeoman** to scaffold an **AngularJS** App. I want to change the default sub generator templates. I have found the template files and was wondering what is the right approach, overwriting the original files or creating my own templates, and if so, does it mean I should create a new generator?

Answer (score 0):

> does it mean I should create a new generator?

Basically yes.

Yeoman don't allow you to switch templates from generator. This is not how it works.

But you could compose a new generator on top of `generator-angular` and just switch the parts you don't need.

See documentation here: http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html